Random spikes in memory usage for WordPress website?
Please bear with me here. I'm not sure as I write this what code/information to supply, but please don't hesitate to ask.
I run a WordPress website that's hosted by GoDaddy and uses cPanel for the backend interface. There have been two incidents lately where the website's memory and CPU usage dramatically spiked from relatively low baseline levels to nearly max capacity. The first incident, CPU usage went from a baseline of 14% to 100%. The second instant affected only the physical memory but it also maxed it out.
The first time this occurred, I tried to research as much as I could. A lot of threads suggested that it could be due to malicious traffic. Therefore I installed a firewall from a plug-in and another plug-in that limits login attempts to prevent a brute force login attack. This was about 3 weeks ago. Nothing had occurred until just today where the spike in memory occurred and the site went down.
Any ideas what could possibly be causing this? I tried to talk to GoDaddy tech support, but they kept insisting it's due to unoptimized plug-ins, but I don't understand how that causes the random spikes in resource usage?

Here's what might help you:
Install Query Monitor This plugin helps track memory usage, CPU usage, and slow database queries. It's a great tool for identifying performance issues.
Google Analytics To monitor sudden traffic spikes and see if they're causing the load.
Some plugins can be resource-intensive, especially if they're not optimized or conflicting with others. Try disabling them one by one to find the problematic one.
GoDaddy support might say it's due to unoptimized plugins because they can indeed cause sudden spikes in resource usage. Plugins can consume a lot of resources, especially if they create numerous database queries or perform heavy operations. Unoptimized or conflicting plugins can strain the server, leading to sudden resource usage spikes. Make sure your plugins are up to date and don't conflict with each other.

Thanks for your reply and for the plugin recommendations. Could a plugin really be that resource intensive to hog that much memory when our baseline levels are so low? Our plugins don't (according to WordPress) conflict with each normally. This spike in memory usage was completely out of the blue.

use a CDN like cloudflare, maybe you are getting a bot attack.
